# A problem with an old computer PSU (schaffer-bv-223-5-04008)

Tags: power-supply, voltage, output, computers

I'm trying to find out the reason why an old PSU is not providing output voltage. Some times ago, I asked for help on retrocomputing (here is the thread: [schaffer-bv-223-5-04008 unidentified components](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/what-are-these-electronic-components-found-inside-a-schaffer-bv-223-5-04008-psu)). Trying to restore the PSU, I've checked almost everything I could think of, but without luck. Here the scheme:

[image: Source: Bo Zimmerman]

As you can see the scheme is dated and less than good quality, in any case is the only we have for this specific model. What I done until now:

- Changed the Zener diodes
- Changed the transistor (T1, T2, T3, T4 all of them are BC327 or BC337)
- Changed the IC (LM339N)
- Tested the remaining diodes
- Changed the C102 and C108 since they were blown
- Changed the C8 and C113 with new ones (reading them they were good, but I changed them
  in any case)
- Unsoldered the TR1 and the TR2 and checked for shorts (they seem good)

What I can read now:

- Correct voltage on P3/PIN5 and P3/PIN1 (orange cables) that is 9V, that means the TR3 is
  correctly working
- No voltage on P4/PIN2, P4/PIN4, P3/PIN4, that should be 5V and 12V (not sure about the
  color associated to the voltage, since there are no references)

Last sad word: there is no part list for this model, but I have the photos on the other thread (I link them here)

[image: Schaffer bv-223-5-04008 Top]

[image: Schaffer bv-223-5-04008 Bottom]

About the bottom picture, I took it just after the caps replacement... Legs are gone, don't worry.

Finally a super help from [Alex Hajnal](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/7347/alex-hajnal) on the other topic to map the scheme to the photo:

[image]

Comment: If you don't know which parts are used, how did you know which zeners or other components to use?

Comment: Hello justme, unsoldering them I was able to read the model, and just changed with new ones or equivalents. Usually this schemes come with a couple of pages of components, but that is not the case, and the only way to identify a component is just remove it and check.